# android studio prompt code complete color and font doesn't work

Tags: user-interface, components, android-studio

both prompt and code complete are not working in android studio.

also color and font are trouble some.

checked configuration is ok.

reinstall doesn't work.

i think it should missing some file or there is some problem in ui component.

BTW,in osx.

====================================

find the answer,i chosed the power save mode,which in file menu.
i don't think power save mode is a goods function.just like the shit.